# How to calculate expected ad bid revenue?

Tags: distributions, expected-value

If there are two ad bidders X and Y, the bid amount is uniform [0,1] distribution. What is a good way to calculate the expected revenue? And if there are more than two bidders, what are the expected revenue?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear to me...

1. Is *each* bid amount $Unif [0, 1]$?

If so, consider using the expectation of the second order statistic of two uniform distributions. If there are $n$, people find the mean of th $n$th order statistic.

2. Or is the bid amount a function of the number of people involved in the auction?  Is the bid amount $Unif [0, n-1]$ where $n$ is the number of people?

Then the answer could be super simple: just use expectation of $Unif [0, n-1]$.

3. Does the bid amount not change with the number of people involved? Stays $Unif [0, 1]$.

Again, super simple: one could just use the expectation of one uniformly distributed random variable.